# SQL Server push notification to VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Is there any way in SQL Server to send back a response on VB.NET (like push notification) every time I wound insert a record and it will send a response to my application?

The process is something like this.

```
APP(CLIENT) -> INSERT_RECORD_TO_DB -> DB_RESPONSE_BACK_TO_APP -> APP(RECEIVE THE RESPONSE)
```

The application will be use as (support ticketing application) that every time someone needs a support they will just send specific support ticket and it will notify us.

Is this possible application for desktop app aside from using timer?

Comment: Notify the app how? You could write a sqlclr trigger and do virtually whatever you want there.

Comment: Firstly, you're not talking about a response.  You already receive a response when inserting a record.  You're talking about a notification to someone other then the person who inserted the record though.  As for the question, assuming that you have a small number of clients listening, you could make use of the `SqlDependency` class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney further question, does the `SqlDependency` supports `LinQ`?

Comment: You might think it does but your question actually doesn't make sense. You would receive a notification via the `SqlDependency` and then you would use your usual data access technology to query the database in whatever way was appropriate based on that notification.  In order for it to make sense for something to support LINQ, that something must be queryable, which a notification is not.

Comment: Thank you for the concept @jmcilhinney